# Removing a post from the results of a WP Query

Tags: posts, query

We have a complicated database query and we would like to exclude some posts. We've tried to do it with SQL, but it's really complicated. The simplest solution seems to loop through the results after the query's made and then exclude a few posts. The problem is, i don't know where to do it! I've tried to unset posts in $wp_query->posts, but they still show up. Is there a proper way to do this? Is there another array WordPress uses that I should unset from?

Comment: Please show your actual code (query) and explain your exact problem.

Answer (score 0):

Do you know the ID of the posts? Have you passed post__not_in as part of your query?

```
$query = new WP_Query( array( 'post_type' => 'post', 'post__not_in' => array( 2, 5, 12, 14, 20 ) ) );
```

From: http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query. The above will return all posts but exclude the IDs specified.

Or do you have another way to group the posts you do not want i.e. by a category or author? A bit of context might help :)

Comment: It's a website for renting apartments. We want to only show properties that will be available in the next 3 months.

Comment: And how are you specifying when it might be available – custom fields?